# Photo in gallery is not timestamped when created by Intent with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action

Tags: android, timestamp, gallery, photo, exif

I figured this question would have been answered elsewhere already but I am having no luck finding an answer.

I am taking a photo through my application by generating an image URI and starting an activity with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE as an action like so;

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
        myActivity.this.startActivityForResult(t, MY_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After I have received the result I get the file path and look at the exif data like so;

```
            Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                //Get file path from last stored photo
                capturedImageFilePath = new String(cursor.getString(column_index_data));
            }
            cursor.close();

            ExifInterface e = new ExifInterface(capturedImageFilePath);
            String dateTime = e.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
```

The exifData contains the correct dateTime however if I look at photo details in the gallery the photo's date is '01/01/1970 01:00'. I cannot understand why this is.

NOTE: For clarity I have left out exception handling and other code which I don't believe to be relevant. I have also made sure that no exceptions are thrown without my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you store the image in a gallery? Would the following be of help?
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery

Comment: Truth be told after viewing that article I'm surprised they were saving to the gallery at all! This solved the problem anyway, many thanks.